# Select all rows where new dateStart and new DateEnd not Intersection. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have table SOME_TABLE

```
id   date_start     date_end
0    05.01.2017     09.01.2017
...
```

I need select for get all rows where my new date_start and new date_end with Intersection.

if

```
new date_start = 01.01.2017 and new date_end  10.01.2017
or new date_start = 06.01.2017 and new date_end  06.01.2017
or new date_start = 01.01.2017 and new date_end  06.01.2017
or new date_start = 08.01.2017 and new date_end  10.01.2017
```

I need get this rows and if

```
new date_start = 22.12.2016 and new date_end  31.12.2016
or new date_start = 15.01.2017 and new date_end 22.01.2017
```

I need not select this rows.

[image]

I create select but it not work

```
select *
  from SOME_TABLE t
 where (to_date('02.04.2017', 'dd.MM.yyyy') >= t.date_start AND
       to_date('02.04.2017', 'dd.MM.yyyy') <= t.date_end)
    OR to_date('11.04.2017', 'dd.MM.yyyy') > t.date_start
```

if date not Intersection this select return rows does not matter

EDIT if this answer:

> If start and end dates can be out of order, i.e., if it is possible
>   that startA > endA or startB > endB, then you also have to check that
>   they are in order, so that means you have to add two additional
>   validity rules: (StartA <= EndB) and (StartB <= EndA) and (StartA <=
>   EndA) and (StartB <= EndB) or: (StartA <= EndB) and (StartA <= EndA)
>   and (StartB <= EndA) and (StartB <= EndB) or, (StartA <= Min(EndA,
>   EndB) and (StartB <= Min(EndA, EndB)) or: (Max(StartA, StartB) <=
>   Min(EndA, EndB)

How can I Remake my select like it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: It is not called "intersection".  It is called "overlap".

Answer (score -1):

Two date ranges [intersect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) if one starts before the other ends (`start1 < end2`) and it also ends after the other starts (`end1 > start2`). So, this will get the rows that do not instersect with other rows in your table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   some_table x
  WHERE  x.start_date < t.end_date
  AND    x.end_date   > t.start_date
)
```

If you also need to consider ranges intersecting if one starts at the same date and time as the other ends then change the conditions from `<`/`>` to `<=`/`>=`.

If you just want to consider rows that intersect / do not intersect a given date range then to get the non-intersecting ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE  end_date   <= :your_start_date
OR     start_date >= :your_end_date
```

And to get the intersecting ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE  end_date   > :your_start_date
AND    start_date < :your_end_date
```

**Update**:

> If start and end dates can be out of order

Use `LEAST( start_date, end_date )` to get the lower value and `GREATEST( start_date, end_date )` to get the higher value. I.e. you can change the first query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   some_table x
  WHERE  LEAST( x.start_date, x.end_date )    < GREATEST( t.start_date, t.end_date )
  AND    GREATEST( x.start_date, x.end_date ) > LEAST( t.start_date, t.end_date )
)
```